# How can i make 3d tetris with blocks with different properties

Tags: python, 3d, tetris

I am a novice at programming and need some guidelines.
My goal is to make a script that takes different blocks with different sizes, properties and connection points between them and autofills a given volume in the most efficient way possible given a desired output.
My first ideea is to make a 3d tetris, made some 3d matrices where 0 is empty space, 1 is the block itself(a simple cube), and the rest of the numbers are the rules on how they connect to each other.

Any hints, tips and tricks or any useful info so i could start working on it would me much appreciated!

````
#0 = empty space
#1 = block space
#2 = connector connection
#3 = firepiece -> barrel
#4 = packer -> connector
#5 = pellet -> packer
#6 = compactor -> packer
connector   = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,2,0],[2,1,2],[0,2,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]]])
firepiece   = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,3,0],[2,1,2],[0,2,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]]])
gauge       = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,2,0],[2,1,2],[0,2,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]]])
packer      = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,4,0],[4,1,4],[0,5,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,0]]])
pellet      = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,5,0],[5,1,5],[0,5,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,0]]])
compactor   = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,6,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,6,0],[6,1,6],[0,6,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,6,0],[0,0,0]]])
barrel      = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,3,0],[0,1,0],[0,3,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]])```
````

Comment: You need to provide an initial coding effort at a minimum.  Then, the community can analyze what you have coded and offer suggestions.

Comment: Done, well that was the easy part.

Comment: The code you shared shows your choice to use a 3x3x3 numpy array as a data structure to represent pieces in a game, but nothing else. What exactly is the problem you're asking about? Are you just asking how to write a game in general? "Show me how to solve this problem with code" is not [on topic for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).